# Can't access old OS after dual booting with windows 7

Tags: multi-boot, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

I recently installed Windows Server 2012 R2 on a dual boot config on my system on a second partition. But after I installed it it changed the drive letters and now I can't access the old Operating system, so when I start I can only start windows server 2012 r2 and not windows 7. I can see all of the files but for the windows 7 machine but can't boot into it when i start the computer. thanks for your help

Comment: Same problem as yours: http://www.sevenforums.com/installation-setup/244854-dual-boot-windows-7-pro-windows-server-2008-boot-loader.html